# d3 - zoom to bounding box of SVG map element via imported .svg (not json)

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm trying to mimic this example here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541 (Zoom to Bounding Box) but with an imported .svg file instead of geoJSON or topoJSON.

This is what I have so far: https://pastebin.com/zT3GmeT6 (index.html and example.svg)

In Mike Bostock's example, he bind the data in his topojson map to objects with

`.data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)`

which is passed to the clicked() function. I've managed to implement the zoom and pan feature with my map but I can't find any info on binding my 'rect'(s) to the objects.

Any help or fiddles would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.